# How to pass bulk participants to Challonge REST API?

Tags: javascript, rest, curl, google-apps-script

I am trying to add a number of participants to a tournament using the Challonge API, see https://api.challonge.com/v1/documents/participants/bulk_add.

My original attempt was using Google apps script:

```
query_url = "https://api.challonge.com/v1/tournaments/" + tourn_id + "/participants/bulk_add.json";
payload = {"api_key" : api_key, "name" : players};
options = {"method" : "POST", "muteHttpExceptions" : true, "contentType": "application/json", "payload" : JSON.stringify(payload)};
response = UrlFetchApp.fetch(query_url, options);
Logger.log("");
Logger.log(response);
```

This logged a response "[]" and no participants were added to the tournament. There was no HTTP error or any other type of error. I thought that this might be an issue with the Google apps script code, so I also tried a request with curl:

```
curl -X POST -H "Content-Type: application/json" --data '{"name":["testname", "testname2"]}' "https://<username>:<api_key>@api.challonge.com/v1/tournaments/<tournament id>/participants/bulk_add.json"
```

The result is the same: no HTTP error, but the participants aren't added to the tournament.

Can anyone see anything wrong with these requests? Note that there is no problem with other requests from the Challonge API, e.g. I can add a single participant via https://api.challonge.com/v1/documents/participants/create.

Comment: what's the payload that worked for creating a single participant? Based on the Challonge docs you your payload might need to look like `{"api_key": <your key>, "participants": <array of participant data> }`

Comment: For a single participant it was just a single string for the name: {"api_key" : api_key, "name" : "testname"}. The 'players' variable in the payload above for bulk adding is an array of strings, e.g. ["testname1", "testname2"], so yeah that's what I'm using.

Comment: hmm I'm not familiar with the api but I did find this PHP library: https://github.com/teamreflex/ChallongePHP/wiki/4.-Tournaments#bulk-add-participant it might help you out

Comment: What does your `players` variable looks like?

Comment: The players variable looks like [player1, player2, player3, ...], where each player is a string. So after the JSON.stringify, the name parameter prints as: "name":["player1","player2","player3",...].

Comment: You need to add an array of object data, not an array of primitives. `[{name: "George", ..}, {name: "Greg", .. }, ..]` and your names must be unique.

Comment: Sorry for the late reply, just had a chance to try it. I replaced the data in the curl request with '[{"name" : "testname"}, {"name" : "testname2"}]' as per your suggestion, with the same result (no participants added). For the Apps Script version, I'm not sure how I should be inputting it. Having "name : [{name : player1}, {name : player2}]" wouldn't really make sense (just to make sure, I tried and it doesn't work). I also tried adding ?name=player1&name=player2 at the end of the query url, which didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

I was running into a similar issue. Here is an example body that I used to get it working:

```js
// This is the URL /tournaments/your_tournament_id/participants/bulk_add.json
{
    "api_key" : "your API key goes here",
    "participants" : [{"name" : "hello w0rld", "misc" : "optional field"}, 
                      {"name" : "hello w0rld2", "misc" : "optional field"}]
}
```